# Oracle offset fetch as optional

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a question regarding using offset depending on how many rows returned. I use oracle 12c.

Here is example of my overly simplyfied query:

> SELECT  COUNT(*) OVER () total, name, fullname
>    
> FROM person
>    
> ORDER BY name
>    
> offset 2 rows
>    
> fetch next 3 rows only

what i want to achive is that the offset and fetch is to be done only when **total** greater than *x* (e.g 100)

I've tried this, but it's not a valid query

> SELECT  COUNT(*) OVER () total, name, fullname
>    
> FROM person
>    
> ORDER BY name
>    
> CASE (total > 100) THEN (offset 2 rows
>    
> fetch next 3 rows only)

Thx before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps you should use `row_number()` instead:

```
WITH p AS (
      SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () as total, name, fullname,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as seqnum
      FROM person p
     )
SELECT p.total, p.name, p.fullname
FROM p
WHERE (total > 100 AND seqnum BETWEEN 3 AND 5) OR
      (total <= 100 AND seqnum <= 3)
ORDER BY name ;
```

Comment: Can you explain?